# Translate file with Google Translator Java API

Tags: google-translate

I´m using this code:

```
GttService myService = new GttService("ex1cor.ex1Ap.1");
myService.setUserCredentials("example@gmail.com", "password");

DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();

// Set source language
String srcLang = "en";
entry.setSourceLanguage(new SourceLanguage(srcLang));

// Set target language
String targetLang = "ja";
entry.setTargetLanguage(new TargetLanguage(targetLang));

// Set title
String title = "Test";
entry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));

// Set local file for upload.
String filename = "D:\\translate\\english.txt";
File file = new File(filename);
String mimeType = "text/plain";

MediaFileSource fileSource = new MediaFileSource(file, mimeType);
MediaContent content = new MediaContent();
content.setMediaSource(fileSource);
content.setMimeType(new ContentType(mimeType));
entry.setContent(content);

URL feedUrl = new URL("http://translate.google.com/toolkit/feeds/documents");

DocumentEntry resultEntry = myService.insert(feedUrl, entry);
```

Nothing happened. No errors... just nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Google Translator Toolkit API doesn't offer document translation services. It offers only document management for now. If you want to get something translated, you might want to look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java). It works very well, but it has some flaws. For instance there is a limit of 5000 characters for a document. This API doesn't take care of it because it is not primarily supposed for document translation, but rather for translation of many little pieces of text.